# How to train identical torch.nn.Modules with different parameters in parallel in GPU

Tags: parallel-processing, pytorch

I have two instances `obj1` and `obj2` of a pytorch nn.Module like this one

```
class Embedding(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, dropout=0, emb_dim):
        self.lin = nn.Linear(1, emb_dim)
        init.xavier_uniform(self.lin1.weight, gain=np.sqrt(2.0))

    def forward(self, values)
        return F.relu(self.lin1(values))
```

And I have two tensors of data `t1`, `t2`
I would like to do

```
obj1.forward(t1)
obj2.forward(t2)
```

in parallel in the GPU, and intuitively this would have to be possible to do, since I am executing the same operations but with different data.
Is there any way I can use pytorch so I can do this?

Comment: I think this can be done by creating two different optimizers `opt1` and `opt2` with different parameters and using them to update each `nn.Module` independently

Comment: do you want to specifically run these two layers on different GPUs or you want to parallelize your whole model on multiple GPUs?

Comment: Wasi Ahmad I want to be able to run both in one gpu at the same time.